# I want to know about the synodic and sidereal months. Why is there a difference between the two?

Tags: reference-frames, terminology, astronomy, earth, moon

I want to know about the synodic and sidereal months. Why is there a difference between the two?

Comment: just read wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month. or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Month

Answer (score 1):

The sidereal month is the time for the moon to complete one revolution and come back into alignment between the center of the earth and a distant star.  The synodic month is the time to come back into alignment with the sun.  They are different because the orbital motion of the earth causes the sun to shift position relative to the background stars by about 30 degrees/month. It takes the moon about two days to go that extra 30 degrees.